# ModelState.AddModelError not displaying error in view - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to solve this issue.

I have this view controller

```
public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(LoginClass model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginClass model, string ReturnUrl)
        {

            if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return this.View(model);
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl) && ReturnUrl.Length > 1 && ReturnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !ReturnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !ReturnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                       return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user name or password provided is incorrect");
                }


            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login", model);

        }

        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

    }
```

and here is my view:

```
<section id="login">
    <div class="container">
        <form action="~/Login/Login" id="Login" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        <label for="password">Remember Me?</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkPersist" name="chkPersist" />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        @Html.ValidationSummary()
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

My issue is that my error message is not appearing when I enter the wrong username and password. Why is not displaying?

Comment: what happens when you do @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

Comment: Same result, no error message appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the last line in your `Login` method. You are calling `RedirectToAction` instead of `View`. This has the consequence that you lose all your view specific state including the model state and validation errors that you built up in your `Login` Action. You can change your `Login` method like so (I simplified it a little), really the only change is replacing `RedirectToAction("Index", "Login", model)` with `View(model)` on the last line.

If you do want to redirect in the event of authentication failure and you did want to use `RedirectToAction` then see my other answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36473835/1260204).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginClass model, string ReturnUrl)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        return this.View(model);

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl) && ReturnUrl.Length > 1 && ReturnUrl.StartsWith("/")
            && !ReturnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !ReturnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
        {
           return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user name or password provided is incorrect");
    return this.View(model); // return to the same view to show your error message

    // return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login", model); // do not redirect
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a placeholder by using the Html Helper function to display the message.

```
 <div>@Html.ValidationMesssage("KeyName")</div>
```

to your view so that you can display the validation message.

The KeyName comes from controller

```
  ModelState.AddModelError("KeyName", "The user name or password provided is incorrect");
```

Also you may need to ensure client side validation is enabled in your web.config.(usually they are)

```
 <appSettings>
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
 </appSettings>
```

Comment: what happens when you do @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

Comment: same result...nothing

Comment: i guess another thing to check is whether jquery is available on that page?

Comment: jquery is available on the page and the items in my web config are there.

Comment: i am not seeing anything wrong with your code. Can  you try moving your @Html.ValidationSummary code line as given in the example here http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2011/01/28/aspnet-mvc-3-client-side-validation-summary-with-jquery-validation-unobtrusive-javascript.aspx